# Postgres cannot insert single quote and semicolon together issue

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create an insert query which contains the the semicolon and single quote together and i escaped the single quote already but the query still does not works until i remove the semi colon. Please help

Not Working

```
INSERT INTO users (email, website) VALUES ('demo@demo.com',
 '=The_Dos_And_Don\'ts Business3735841;n=6')
```

Working (Semicolon Removed)

```
INSERT INTO users (email, website) VALUES ('demo@demo.com', 
'=The_Dos_And_Don\'ts Business3735841n=6')
```

Comment: The `\'` should not work. It should be `''` The semicolon works without any problems: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=29f320f42a354af583837e5faec9ebdd

Answer (score 1):

Postgres **8.4**:
Both ways work, escaping with `\'` and `''`, see the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=f64726f5da53b0d2f41851e097b04bff).
Postgres **9.4+**:
Only `''` works, see the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=f64726f5da53b0d2f41851e097b04bff).
The semicolon does not affect the result.

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon should not make any problems:
[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=ed1b991959a618b9db2261c431c6b218)

The escape of the single quote should be done with `''`:
[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=b78c6e56e5e2054660d486e6cca11c7b)

Both in combination is no problem as well: 
[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=8db8c83cf8de8b2b3706ad26d0fb5421)

Your code works fine if the escape of the single quote would be done correctly:
[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=29f320f42a354af583837e5faec9ebdd)

Comment: @AmanBansal Did this help? If so, please do not forget to accept (showing that the problem is solved) and upvote (honors the work of the repliers) the relevant answers :)